# Getting Error=Missing Registration while sending HTTPPost to GCM Using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, android, json, google-apps-script, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send http post to GCM server using google apps script. I have the device ID and the proper credentials. Here is the code I am using:

```
function doThat(){
  var url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "key=myAPIKEY",
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
    },
    "payload": {
      "data": {
        "score": "5x1",
        "time": "15:10"
      },
      "registration_ids": ["regid1"]
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log("Response: "+response.toString());
}
```

Here, myAPIKEY and regid1 are place holders. 
An equivalent java code works well for this. Hence there seems no problem with the credentials. 
I went through [this](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html) link of android documentation to find the format of json to be sent to GCM server as(Those who edit this code below note that the api keys and others are directly taken from that [link](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html) on android GCM site. ITS NOT MINE.SO PLS DO NOT CHANGE IT):

```
    Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyB-1uEai2WiUapxCs2Q0GZYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "registration_ids" : ["APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx..."],
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

Note: If
I always get "Error=Missing Registration" at Logger.log() statement in execution logs. The java equivalent code works perfect. But google script gives this error.So what is wrong here?

Comment: I tried to edit it but you should NEVER put an api key online. Please, I beg you, don't do it. People will scrape it and use it for their own projects(I really hope you aren't paying for it, if so make a new key). This might be paranoid but that is akin to a password...

Comment: @JZL003 i did not put in the api key. The thing u edited was taken from https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html . So that key was on google's public website and not mine.

Comment: I'm sorry, I jumped the gun, I was too flummoxed by the authentic look of it(I had just seen a different question with an actual ID in it). Sorry again

Comment: @JZL003 nothing to be sorry about it!. In fact its a good job. Exposing api secrets is a dangerous thing on the web. So infact I am grateful for your attempt!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the contentType advanced argument and stringify your payload. See this sample for pointers:

https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/blob/master/Android/SharedDb.gs

Comment: I had found the solution before you posted the answer. I saw the video by that person(Arun Nagarajan) from google. https://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=RSgMEtRl0sw But anyways thanks for the answer.Accepting with upvote!!